# Install a program from the network

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-vista, deployment

In Windows there is a place under the Control Panel called Get Programs and Install a program from the network (in Win 7 at least), possibly a slightly different name in Vista, but it was there too.

The question is basically: How do you publish programs to that so users can go there and install?

Bonus follow up: Is it a good way to deploy optional programs? (Compared to using GPO's.)

In Windows 7 you can go to Control Panel, Programs, Programs and Features, and on the left hand menu: Install a program from the network.

Comment: Asking two questions makes it difficult to properly award good answers. You should break this into two questions. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ***IS*** where you install programs that are published (as opposed to "assigned") via GPOs.

Comment: You're right! For some reason a couple of hours, a couple of gpupdates and a restart did not trigger and populate the list. However, this morning my test application was there!

Comment: I must say though, that this should REALLY be documented better. Bad MS...

Comment: A bit old (for Win2003), but this is a nice guide: https://www.clarosoftware.com/help/how-to-use-group-policy-to-remotely-install-software-in-windows-server-2003/

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching for the past 30 minutes to find the answer to your question and it appears that there is not a single shred of documentation on installing a program from the network other than this ridiculously non-detailed page: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Install-a-program  At first I believed it would be publishing apps via GPO's but this isn't the case.

It would seem as if there is a specific way to "*advertise*" applications. That's the term I keep finding. However, I cannot find any information beyond that. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Isn't that what happens when you publish an application via GPO?!?

Comment: It may be and that would make perfect sense. What doesn't make sense is the lack of documentation on a product that has been available for 3/4's of a year.

Comment: Gomibushi, please try publishing an MSI via GPO (http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Group-Policy-Deploy-Applications.html) and see if the applications are available under the "Install a program from the network" listing.

Comment: Given Microsoft's habit with Windows Vista/7 of moving around and renaming things that have been around since Windows NT, this is *very* plausible...

Comment: @Massimo: Nope! It is not! I tested that a year ago with SCE2007 and Vista, and again now with SCE2010 and Win7. I _think_ it is set by some reg setting, pointing to a share or something...

Comment: @JohnyD Thanks, but I have google'd the internet up and down... no documentation no where. Might of course be in some book, so I hoped someone here might have read something.

Comment: I rescind my previous comment @Massimo - You are correct.